# Компиляция каждую секунду

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, asp.net-core-2

У меня есть проект на `ASP.NET Core 2.0` на основе default `React template`.

Когда я его запускаю в консоль постоянно (в непрерывном режиме) выводятся сообщения о сборке webpack. Судя по этим сообщениям он каждую секунду перекомпилирует клиентский проект (Webpack + React + Typescript).

Кстати там так же стоит Hot Module Replacement. Но я, честно говоря не понимаю зачем его каждую секунду перекомпилировать и тратить столько ресурсов, можно же перекомпилировать только в том случае если файлы изменены?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
            alias: {
                "ClientApp": path.resolve('./ClientApp')
            }
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                {
                    test: /\.less$/, use: [{
                        loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings 
                    }, {
                        loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS 
                    }, {
                        loader: "less-loader" // compiles Less to CSS 
                    }]
                },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                { test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" },
                { test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader" },
                {
                    test: require.resolve('tinymce/tinymce'), loaders: [
                        'imports-loader?this=>window',
                        'exports-loader?window.tinymce'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /tinymce\/(themes|plugins)\//,
                    loaders: [
                        'imports-loader?this=>window'
                    ]
                }   
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                'window.$': '/jquery'//,
                //Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
            }),
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
        ])
    }];
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/history": "4.6.0",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/react": "16.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.3",
    "@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.5",
    "@types/react-router": "4.0.17",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "4.2.1",
    "@types/tinymce": "4.5.14",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.2",
    "@types/date-arithmetic": "3.1.1",
    "@types/query-string": "5.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.3.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "less": "2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "4.0.5",
    "mobx": "3.3.1",
    "mobx-react": "4.3.4",
    "mobx-react-devtools": "4.2.15",
    "mobx-utils": "3.2.1",
    "popper.js": "1.12.9",
    "react": "16.1.1",
    "react-dom": "16.1.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "3.1.3",
    "react-router": "4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
    "react-tinymce": "0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "tinymce": "4.7.2",
    "typescript": "2.6.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "3.8.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.20.0",
    "react-tagsinput": "3.19.0",
    "date-arithmetic": "3.1.0",
    "query-string": "5.0.1"
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "types": [ "webpack-env" ],
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "paths": {
      "ClientApp/*": [ "./ClientApp/*" ]
    },
    "lib": [ "es2016", "dom" ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "bin",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70908/discussion-between-daniel-khoroshko-and--).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70911/discussion-on-question-by-----).